# How to open paint through MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, paint

Is there a way through which we can open MS Paint from MATLAB?

Comment: If you accept a few answers, people will be more willing to help!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
system('mspaint');
```

if you want to open a specific file then build up the string with the correct filename

Answer (score 0):

try

```
winopen('image.bmp')
```

or try

```
help system
help dos
help unix
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open MS Paint and *immediately* return control to MATLAB (i.e. MATLAB won't wait for the program to be closed), then you can issue a command to the operating system using the [bang operator `!`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_env/f0-12994.html#f0-38522) like so:

```
!mspaint &
```

Or you could use the [SYSTEM](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/system.html) command as [mor22 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5580111/how-to-open-paint-through-matlab/5580242#5580242) with `&` added to the end of the string:

```
system('mspaint &');
```